# Why my const variable can't be found in different mod

Tags: rust

I define a const variable in main.rs and want to use it in different file.

in `src/main.rs`, I define such const, no matter and pub or not, it didn’t use:

```
const CONFIG_GROUP: &str = "core.hydra.io";
pub const CONFIG_VERSION: &str = "v1alpha1";
pub const COMPONENT_CRD: &str = "componentschematics";

fn main() {
...
}
```

and in another file `src/abc.rs`, I want use this const.

It doesn't work, whether use `::` or not.

```
println!("{}", COMPONENT_CRD); 
let component_resource = RawApi::customResource(COMPONENT_CRD)
    .within(top_ns.as_str())
    .group(::CONFIG_GROUP)
    .version(::CONFIG_VERSION);
```

It reports :

```
    |
208 |         println!("{}", COMPONENT_CRD);
    |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope
error[E0425]: cannot find value `CONFIG_CRD` in this scope
   --> src/abc.rs:209:54
    |
209 |         let config_resource = RawApi::customResource(CONFIG_CRD)
    |                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `CONFIG_VERSION` in the crate root
   --> src/abc.rs:210:24
    |
210 |             .version(::CONFIG_VERSION)
    |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in the crate root

error[E0425]: cannot find value `CONFIG_GROUP` in the crate root
   --> src/abc.rs:211:22
    |
211 |             .group(::CONFIG_GROUP)
    |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in the crate root
```

Comment: Did you add the `use` ?

Comment: 8 | use CONFIG_CRD;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^ no `CONFIG_CRD` external crate

can not use `use`

Comment: What @DenysSéguret said, did you write `use pkg_name::CONFIG_CRD` in `src/abc.rs`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that we're talking about Rust 2018 edition. I'd recommend to read the [Path clarity](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/module-system/path-clarity.html) section, especially this part:

> The prefix `::` previously referred to either the crate root or an external crate; it now unambiguously refers to an external crate. For instance, `::foo::bar` always refers to the name `bar` inside the external crate `foo`.

Use can't use `::CONFIG_VERSION`, `::main::CONFIG_VERSION`, etc. Couple of options:

- Use `crate::CONFIG_VERSION` directly
- Import it `use crate::CONFIG_VERSION` and use just `CONFIG_VERSION`

`abc.rs` content:

```rust
pub(crate) fn foo() {
    println!("{}", crate::CONFIG_VERSION);
}
```

Another `abc.rs` variant:

```rust
use crate::CONFIG_VERSION;

pub(crate) fn foo() {
    println!("{}", CONFIG_VERSION);
}
```

`main.rs` content:

```rust
pub(crate) const CONFIG_VERSION: &str = "v1alpha1";

mod abc;

fn main() {
    abc::foo()
}
```

Comment: I write `use crate::CONFIG_CRD;` in `abc.rs` but it tell  no `CONFIG_CRD` in the root.  While I write `pub(crate) const CONFIG_CRD: &str = "operationalconfigurations";`  just like you said.

my version is:
```
rustc 1.36.0 (a53f9df32 2019-07-03)
```

Comment: I found that I must write this const before `mod abc;` why?

Comment: I find it'll be more complicated if I  define `pub(crate) const CONFIG_VERSION: &str = "v1alpha1";` and `mod abc;` in another file `src/lib.rs`.

Then I can use const in `src/abc.rs`, while I can't use it in `main.rs` now.

Comment: Then drop the `(crate)` and use just `pub`. See [Visibility](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/mod/visibility.html).